# Как выровнять текст по центру?

Tags: html, css

Код:

```css
.test {       
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.aqw {
    text-align: center;
}
.aqw2 {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="aqw">dsfsdfsdfs</div>
    <div class="aqw">dsfsdfsdfs</div>
    <div class="aqw">dsfsdfsdfs</div>
    <div class="aqw">dsfsdfsdfs</div>
    <div class="aqw">dsfsdfsdfs</div>
</div> 
<div class="test">
    <span class="aqw2">dsfsdfsdfs</span >
    <span class="aqw2">dsfsdfsdfs</span >
    <span class="aqw2">dsfsdfsdfs</span >
    <span class="aqw2">dsfsdfsdfs</span >
</div>
```

Как только добавляю `float: left;`, текст перестает выстраиваться по центру.

Как мне его выровнять?

Пример в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vz5n9ema/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/vz5n9ema/1/)

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* Параметры рамки */
    padding: 5px;
    /* Поля вокруг текста */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* Отступ снизу */
    position:relative;
    /* выравниваем по центру */
    text-align: center;
}
.aqw2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Вариант 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vz5n9ema/2/) - flexbox

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* Параметры рамки */
    padding: 5px;
    /* Поля вокруг текста */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* Отступ снизу */
    position:relative;
    /* flexbox */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
.test:nth-of-type(1){
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!